# Exclude node module from sideEffects - webpack treeshaking

Tags: typescript, webpack, tree-shaking

We have a SPFx webpart project which renders Adaptive cards - this project generate bundles using Webpack via gulp-tasks.

We also have a (ESM/esnext) typescript library (SPPacking library) which has a lot of utility functions.

```
 |-- My-SPFx-Webpart
    |-- package.json
    |-- node_modules
      |-- Common-Library  
         |--node_modules
            |-- AdaptiveHtml implementing 'toJson' 
         |--Utils.ts file consuming node_module_1 as 'import AdaptiveHtml from "adaptive-html";
```

While trying to setup TreeShaking in the webpart project, we get `Cannot read property 'toJson' of undefined`
We believe one the modules utilized by the library project is being shaken off and we want to avoid tree-shaking for that module (or the file consuming the module) .

> Utils is used in all the files of the SPFX Webpart.

In the package json of SPFx Webpart, is there a way to mark Utils.ts as having sideEffects ?

Things we tried,

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "My SPFx Webpart",
  "sideEffects": [
    "Common-Library",       //tried to mark the whole node_module as sideEffect - not working
    "Common-Library/Utils,  //tried to mark the exported module as sideEffect - not working
    "AdaptiveHtml",         //tried to mark the exported affected node_module as sideEffect - not working

  ],
```

Please help us to mark the node_modules or sub-modules as sideEffect in package json.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to specify whole path.

Do this:

```
"sideEffects": ["./node_modules/Common-Library/Utils]
```